# submit button not working when i combine my codes

Tags: javascript

it was working on when i split them into two but when i combine them the save button isnt working i tried changing the `document.getElementById` to `document.getElementByClassName` but it stops the function of both here is the code

```
<html>
<head>
<body>
<div class="container">         
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id = "table1">
<thead>
  <tr>
        <th><center>Item Name</center> </th>
        <th><center>Brand</center> </th>
        <th><center>Selling Price</center> </th>
        <th><center>Quantity</center> </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id = tbody1>
    <tr>
        <td>Cake</td>
        <td>Pastry</td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Wat</td>
        <td>But</td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>

 </table>
 </div>

 <div class="container">         
 <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id = "table2">
 <thead>
  <tr>
        <th><center>Item Name</center> </th>
        <th><center>Brand</center> </th>
        <th><center>Selling Price</center> </th>
        <th><center>Quantity</center> </th>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody id = "myNewTableBody" class = "tbody2">
 <tr class = "tr2">
 </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
 </div>
    <input type = "submit" value = "save" name = "btnsave" onclick = "myFunction()" style = "position : absolute; top : 550px; left : 20px; font-size: 20px;"/></input>


</body>
    <script>
    var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
    var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
    tbody.onclick = function (e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        var data = [];
        var target = e.srcElement || e.target;
        while (target && target.nodeName !== "TR") {
            target = target.parentNode;
        }
        if (target) {
            var cells = target.getElementsByTagName("td");
            for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
                data.push(cells[i].innerHTML);
            }
        }
        var trnode = document.createElement("tr");

        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            var tdnode = document.createElement("td");
            var textnode = document.createTextNode(data[i]);
            tdnode.appendChild(textnode);
            trnode.appendChild(tdnode);
        }

        document.getElementById("myNewTableBody").appendChild(trnode);
    };
   function myFunction() {
     var rows =     document.getElementById("table2")
    .getElementsByClassName("tbody2")
     [0].getElementsByClassName("tr2").length;
     var a = 1;
     var b = 1;
     for(var i = 0; i < rows; i++){
     var x = 
     document.getElementById("table2").rows[a].cells.item(0).innerHTML
     var y = 
     document.getElementById("table2").rows[a].cells.item(4).innerHTML
     var a = a + 1;
     var b = b + 1;
     alert(x);
     alert(y);
     }
     }

    </script>
    <html>
    <head>
```

heres the seperate code of the save button that's working

```
     <html>
     <head>

     <body>
     <div class="container">         
     <table  id = "table1">
     <thead>
     <tr>
        <th><center>ID</center> </th>
        <th><center>Item Name</center> </th>
        <th><center>Category</center> </th>
        <th><center>Selling Price</center> </th>
        <th><center>Quantity</center> </th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class = "tbody2">
    <tr class = "tr2">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Cake</td>
        <td>Pastry</td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>5</td>
  </tr>
    <tr class = "tr2"> 
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Bread</td>
        <td>Pastry</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>100</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
    <input type = "submit" value = "save" name = "btnsave" 
  onclick = "myFunction()" /></input>


 </body>
 <script>
 function myFunction() {
 var rows = document.getElementById("table1")
 .getElementsByClassName("tbody2")[0]
 .getElementsByClassName("tr2").length;
 var a = 1;
 var b = 1;
 for(var i = 0; i < rows; i++){
 var x = document.getElementById("table1").rows[a].cells.item(0).innerHTML
 var y = document.getElementById("table1").rows[a].cells.item(4).innerHTML
 var a = a + 1;
 var b = b + 1;
 alert(x);
 alert(y);
 }
 }

 </script>
 </html>
```

Comment: Good god man, Punctuation and capitalisation please!

Comment: Both pieces of code have a function called `myFunction` - they will overwrite each other if you try to "combine the codes"!

Comment: the top one is the already combined one

Comment: You may be having trouble with automatic semicolon insertion. That combined code has at least a few lines that might have trouble. Try combining all your multiple line statements into single lines and see if that helps. If it doesn't say what errors you are getting.

Comment: You would have found the error if you just simply debugged as developers are supposed to do..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this code, second table, table with id `table2` is empty. When you take, first column, in it's second row(table body), you get a null. Then you trying to access `innerHTML` property on a `null` element. Add some content to `table2` and run check it again.

Again same problem comes when you say, `document.getElementById("table2").rows[a].cells.item(4).innerHTML`. Here you are trying to access 5th cell of a row, which contains only 4 cells.